# Make first template argument optional

Tags: c++

I have a function that does a base 64 encode using Boost. It takes two template parameters: One for the type of container used for input, and one for the type of container used for output. This allows you to do things like provide binary data using a `std::vector` but get a `std::string` back.

Here's the code:

```
template<typename OutputContainer, typename InputContainer>
OutputContainer Encode(InputContainer const& data)
{
    using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
    using base64_it = base64_from_binary<transform_width<
        typename InputContainer::const_iterator, 6, 8>>;

    OutputContainer result(base64_it(data.begin()), base64_it(data.end()));

    static std::string const padding[] { "", "==", "="};
    auto const& pad = padding[data.size() % 3];
    result.insert(result.end(), pad.begin(), pad.end());

    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::string data = "Hello World!+";
auto encoded = Encode<std::string>(data);
```

Live sample [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Rnz4ZjvgQFMRbH2A)

Note in the example above, I still had to provide the template argument for the output container even though it's the same type as the input container. In these scenarios, I'd like the `OutputContainer` template parameter to be optional and instead use the type deduced by `InputContainer`. I am not sure what workarounds or adjustments I can perform to get this kind of interface, but it would be nice to see what SO community can come up with.

Note I am also open to a more iterator-centric approach, but I avoided it due to redundancy/boilerplate (I think it's simpler to pass in containers than iterators). If it ends up looking like the 4-argument version of `std::transform()` I think I'll be a lot less satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an overload (not a specialization) for the case where `InputContainer` and `OutputContainer` is the same, `enable_if` to disable the original implementation in this case, it's possible to achieve what you're asking for. A caveat is that it will no longer be possible to explicitly specify both container types if they are the same, unless a third argument is also provided:

```
template<typename OutputContainer, typename InputContainer, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<OuptputContainer, InputContainer>>>
OutputContainer Encode(InputContainer const& data)
{
    // Your implementation
}

template<typename OutputContainer>
OutputContainer Encode(OutputContainer const& data)
{
    return Encode<OutputContainer, OutputContainer, void>(data);
}
```

[Example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/7jQjX3).